# Use the same regular expressions across languages like Java and Javascript etc

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Just now I want to learn how to build regular expressions.  When I am going to search in Google, the suggestions are

- regular expressions for Java
- regular expressions for Javascript .... etc

Can I use the same regular expressions for all languages or will it vary from one language to another?  I am really in confusion.

Comment: Regular syntax may vary in different languages.

Comment: there is no standard synatax?

Comment: there could be syntactical and supported feature differences in different languages

Comment: If i want to learn regular expressions i need to learn for all technologies seperately

Comment: Why some one voted to close.Is it not meaning ful question

Comment: @PSR I have voted for closing the question as *"Not constructive"*, since IMO *"... this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"*.

Comment: @VisioN can u explain clearly because i am not good in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is: No!

Languages use different regex engines and these use different syntax. 
From this list you can see there are many: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

The general principle of regular expressions are the same, but the syntax is different.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Many features of regular expressions are the same for many languages (`.*` will work everywhere, for example).

But there is no standard and special features like named groups are implemented differently or not available at all.

Safe features are generally the common stuff: `.*^$` work the same everywhere. But character groups can already cause problems; some languages use `[]`, others need `\[\]`